# pygettext doesn't read strings into the .pot file

Tags: python

I try to make a multilingual application with pygettext. I reproduce the steps described here: https://phrase.com/blog/posts/translate-python-gnu-gettext/.

The translatable strings should appear  at the bottom of the .pot file:

```
#: src/main.py:5
msgid "Hello world"
msgstr ""
#: src/main.py:6
msgid "This is a translatable string"
msgstr ""
```

The problem is that in my case there msgid are empty, though .pot file is created.
It looks like pygettext just doesn't see them in the code.

That's how my whole .pot file looks like:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR ORGANIZATION
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2021-01-16 13:50+0300\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=cp1251\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Generated-By: pygettext.py 1.5\n"
```

My python code:

```
# main.py
import gettext
_ = gettext.gettext


def print_some_strings():
    print(_("Hello world"))
    print(_("This is a translatable string"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_some_strings()
```

Project structure:

```
pdf_invoices
│ └── en
│     └── LC_MESSAGES
│         └── base.pot
└──__main__.py
```

Command creating .pot file:

```
C:\>C:\Users\belose\Anaconda3\Tools\i18n\pygettext.py 
-d C:\Users\belose\PycharmProjects\pdf_invoices\__main__.py 
-o C:\Users\belose\PycharmProjects\pdf_invoices\locales\ru\base.pot
```

Answer (score 2):

You run pygettext in the command line.
But you should run python first.
In your case:

```
    C:\>python C:\Users\belose\Anaconda3\Tools\i18n\pygettext.py
   -d C:\Users\belose\PycharmProjects\pdf_invoices\__main__.py 
   -o C:\Users\belose\PycharmProjects\pdf_invoices\locales\ru\base.pot
```